# Do each DateTime in fact need it's own Date and Time dimention?

Tags: ssas, olap

Lets say i have columns Time1 and Time2 in Fact table. They can differ both in time and date.

In SSAS MOLAP Cube I have statistics  only for Time1 ( Standard Date dimention and my own TimeOfDay dimention). But now i need both times in statistics.

Do I need to duplicate both dimentions and underlying tables for them for each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a role playing dimension.  You don't need to duplicate the underlying tables.  You just create a new cube dimension in your dimension usage tab.  Here's a helpful link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174487%28v=sql.90%29.aspx